# jQuery: Most efficient way to create blocks of HTML based on number of selected items?

Tags: jquery, loops

So I have a basic HTML `<select>` element where a user can select a number.

What I then need to do is create some list items in an unordered list based on the number they selected.

What's the most efficient way to do that with jQuery?

Comment: What will be in the list-items, and does a default list exist once the page is loaded?

Comment: Example: `1 ticket: $ <input type="text" name="" value="" />` And the "1" for ticket would increase with each iteration of the loop.

And default list items don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient method may vary across browsers, but I would imagine that setting the `innerHTML` of a `<ul>` with a string of html elements would offer the best performance.

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ewewa/2)**

```
$("#select").change(function() {
  var val = this.value,
      lis = '';

  for(var i=1; i <= val; i++) {
    lis += '<li> Ticket ' + i + '</li>';
  }  

  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = lis;      
});
```

and HTML

```
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">1 ticket</option>
    <option value="2">2 tickets</option>
    <option value="3">3 tickets</option>
    <option value="4">4 tickets</option>
    <option value="5">5 tickets</option>
    <option value="6">6 tickets</option>   
  </select>

  <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have a snippet of the html inside a div that is "display:none".  Use JQuery to find that snippet.  Then use a for loop to append a clone() of that snippet where you want it.